# c++ compilation error-new initializer expression list treated as compound expression -fpermissive

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to use variadic arguments in the emplace function in vector.h.

In vector_test.h line 38, I used `FUN_AFTER(v1, v1.emplace(v1.begin(), 0**, 1**));`
The function of emplace is defined as

```
template <class T>
template <class ...Args>
typename vector<T>::iterator
vector<T>::emplace(const_iterator pos, Args&& ...args)
{
  MYSTL_DEBUG(pos >= begin() && pos <= end());
  iterator xpos = const_cast<iterator>(pos);
  const size_type n = xpos - begin_;
  if (end_ != cap_ && xpos == end_)
  {
    data_allocator::construct(mystl::address_of(*end_), mystl::forward<Args>(args)...);
    ++end_;
  }
  else if (end_ != cap_)
  {
    auto new_end = end_;
    data_allocator::construct(mystl::address_of(*end_), *(end_ - 1));
    ++new_end;
    mystl::copy_backward(xpos, end_ - 1, end_);
    *xpos = value_type(mystl::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  else
  {
    reallocate_emplace(xpos, mystl::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  return begin() + n;
}
```

The definition of the construct function is

```
template <class Ty, class... Args>
void construct(Ty* ptr, Args&&... args)
{
  ::new ((void*)ptr) Ty(mystl::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

I expected it to insert two elements 0, 1 at the beginning of v1, but I get a compile error

```
new Initializer expression list treated as compound expression ::new ((void*)ptr) Ty(mystl::forward<Args>(args). ..);
```

Variable parameters are used in line 38 of construct.h, why can't  pass in 0 and 1 two actual parameters, I don't understand very well

The original code is linked at https://github.com/Alinshans/MyTinySTL

Comment: If possible, please try to create a [mre] to show us, with emphasis on the minimal part. Also please include the full and complete copy-pasted (as text) build output of the shown example, and add comments in the code where you get the errors.

Comment: Sorry, I tried the minimal reproducible example but it didn't work, it was a bit difficult for me. Give me some more time and I will try again

Comment: From what I understand, the problem is actually mainly in this code`template <class Ty, class... Args>
void construct(Ty* ptr, Args&&... args)
{
  ::new ((void*)ptr) Ty(mystl::forward<Args>(args)...);
}`. The code tries to forget to pass in *ptr, 0, 1 to the construct function, and when running ::new ((void*)ptr) Ty(mystl::forward<Args>(args)...); error "new initializer expression list treated as compound expression -fpermissive" happened

Comment: Far as I can tell, you are calling `construct` with `int*` pointer as the first argument; `Ty` is `int`. So the new expression boils down to `new (some_pointer) int(0, 1);` This last part isn't calling any kind of function with two arguments - it initializes an `int` object with the expression `0, 1`. This is an expression using a comma operator; its value is `1`

Comment: I don't know what you meant to do in your `vector` clone, but be aware that for `std::vector`, `emplace(iterator, arg1, arg2, arg3)` is not meant to insert three elements - it's meant to insert one element whose constructor takes three arguments. `v1.emplace(v1.begin(), 0, 1)` would **not** insert two elements if `v1` were of type `std::vector<int>`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I understand the reason@Igor Tandetnik